# "We found extra characters at the end of json" Excel Power Query

Tags: json, excel, azure, import, powerquery

I want to use Excel Power Query to import JSON data from web and transform the data afterwards. I have 2 versions of JSON Data, one development version and one live version. Both versions had no problem prior to last week and could connect without any issues.
Last week the live version stopped working and couldnt connect through Excel or PowerBI anymore. Curiously, nothing has been changed in both versions that could've contributed to this error happening, there were absolutely no hands in either versions during that time frame.

This is the dev connection string in PowerQuery thats working without problems.

```
Source=
Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.dev.com/dummy/YXC/JSONDATA")),
```

Now when I try to change it to this

```
Source=
Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.live.com/dummy/YXC/JSONDATA")),
```

the error message: **"[DataFormatError] We found extra characters at the end of JSON input."** arises

After this and some troubleshooting, I opened a new empty Excel file to put the link directly into the "from Web" tab. The connection fails and I get up to 2 Errors.

**"[DataFormatError] We found extra characters at the end of JSON input."**

**"Details: The Ressource under "https://www.live.com/dummy/YXC/JSONDATA" cant be opened through Web.Page since its apparently no website"**

Before the website can be openend one must have an authorized microsoft organisation account.
In Chrome the data shows up without any issues and there are no authorization issues, also when I download the JSON data and import it through a file directly there are no issues either. Same error occurs with other accounts.

Since it says DataFormatError, I started looking into the JSON Data. The JSON Data doesnt have any whitespace and is identical with the working dev version.

Does anybody encountered this or has a clue on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a URL that you can actually share? It's very difficult to debug blindly.

Comment: sadly cant reproduce that since its work related